# How to roundup next or previous value

Tags: php, logic

I am trying to **roundup** the `Quantity` while customer adding product to cart. Here I am little bit confusing how can we do this.

For example Product have tier `price` `qty` like 10.

If Customer add 15 then logicallay we need to **roundup** 20, if add 14 then we need to **roundup** 10.

i.e 50% or above we need to **roundup** the next `qty` otherwise we need to **roundup** previous `qty`.

Above example will be easy for us, for doing this business logic.

Can you guys tell me how to do it for below example .

Product have tier price `qty` like **1, 7, 12, 20, 50**.

Not only above example, related logic like some of the product `tier` **price** have **20, 70, 150**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

round() will go to nearest by default.

Divide by 10, do the round, then multiply by 10 to reduce the significant digits.

```
round($input / 10) * 10;
```

Ie:

```
round(14 / 10) * 10; will be 10 and
round(15 / 10) * 10; will be 20
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's work 100%. Let's try and get back to you.

Comment: yeah hope it will help u.. Please accept the answer if it worked.